# False positive Spring LDAP from findbugs-sec-plugin

Tags: java, spotbugs, find-sec-bugs

It looks like it does not take into account that `Filter.toString/encode` can actually encode LDAP filter correctly. So if I have a flags something like

```
Filter filter = blahblah;
ldapTemplate.search("", filter.toString());
```

it would flag that this code is vulnerable to LDAP injection where it should not.

How do I make findsec-bugs-plugin not to flag this kind of usage as an issue?

Comment: Please share the Spotbugs report.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the implementation of the Filter class. The class is not known yet by Find-Security-Bugs. If it is properly escaping potential input, we could easily mark `Filter.toString()` as safe. Is it [the class from UnboundID](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/Filter.html#toString()).

Please [open a ticket on the issue tracker on Find-Security-Bugs](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/issues).